# Is it faster to have a python environment installed with the user that's executing or where the executable file lives

Tags: python, environment, mach

I'm executing a python script on *virtual machine-1* with user *user1* but the executable file lives in filesystem *machine-2:/data/file* which has been mounted to machine-1

Would my python script run faster if the environment/libraries I was using where installed in the home directory for *user1* or in the filesystem where the script is being run from *machine-2:/data/file*

I'm hoping I'm using the right words to describe all the moving parts so let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: It would really depend on how slow these mounts are, and whether what you are doing requires expensive locking. Your best bet is to benchmark the startup and execution times a little and compare.

Comment: I'm assuming it would be faster if all the code was on machine-1, but it depends on your code and your vm and your mount. Better to test it out yourself if it's important to you.